# How to make an asynchronous delayed function?

Tags: python, asynchronous

So, I have a little program, that looks like this:

```
global_cache = {}

def callback(tgi=""):
    if tgi is None:
        page_id = "0"
    else:
        page_id = tgi

    # something to fetch json data from an api to a "blob" object
    # then save the "blob" to the global cache
    blob = {'page_id': page_id, 'data': "some data"}
    global_cache['data'] = blob

    cache_cleaner('data')
    return blob


def cache_cleaner(string):
    time.sleep(60*60) # wait for one hour until it cleans the cache
    global_cache[string] = {}
```

Well, as you can see, the `callback()` function won't return the `blob` data until the sleep in the `cache_cleaner()` function runs out. But I'd like to make that function to be called and wait the time asynchronously, so the `callback()` function can return the data while the time runs for the `cache_cleaner()`.

Also, the `callback()` function is imported in another program, so it is not in the same thread as the main program.

How do I do this?

Comment: If the `callback()` function is imported by another program, it will not only be in another thread, it will be in another process. This also means the `global_cache` will somehow need to referenced by two different processes. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows server RT 2012

Comment: The scope of what you want to do is fairly expansive—too broad for a SO question IMO. Here's an approach that might work: On Windows, background processes are mostly run as Windows Services and using one would be a way to arrange for the cleaner task to run later. You could do that by creating an always-running background service that will launch it at the appropriate time. The [Python for Windows Extensions](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) (aka `pywin32`) has facilities to do this. The `global_cache` could also be provided by the same background service or a separate one.

Comment: Hmm... I see...